# Validation unsuccessful using Xcode

Tags: xcode, itunes-store

When I am validating my app using Xcode every time I am getting two error one is `iTunesSoftwareServiceAuthentication` error and another is `iTunes` store operation failed. I tried validating the build again and again and every time this error comes. Tried everything found on google regarding this but they are not working.
I have attached the screenshot of the error too.

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: Try it separately from application loader.

Comment: Check your developer account, may be your membership for developer has been expired .

Comment: it was expired but i renewed the account

Comment: Try to clean the project and re-download the certificates and provisioning profiles and then try.The same case was with me but after renewing, it worked for me.

Comment: provisioning profile are managed by xcode so i don't think thats the issue

Comment: can you elaborate in steps please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select App Targets then goto General -> Identity -> Change Build number
2. Clean and build your project and then Product -> Archive and after that re-generate `ipa` file and save it in your system.
3. On top left corner click Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Click Application Loader.
4. Login in Application Loader and upload your archive file using Application Loader.

Comment: it wont get rejected by app store. Right ??

Comment: Yes It wont rejected by Apples.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Xcode -> Preferences and remove your developer account details and try adding them again.

2) Try to Clean your project (CMD + Shift + K), close Xcode, restart Xcode and build project again (CMD + B).

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i will try this

Answer (score 0):

This error can be occurred if the membership for the developer account has been expired.

So first visit to developer site to check if this is the case, then apply for renew and then try again.

Comment: account  was expired but i renew it. i already checked the developer account so this is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Once try by `Unselect BitCode` after archive and then try to validate! If it is not work then try after few hours. Sometimes it happens because of apple's server issue also.